# Extracting keys from HTML row

Tags: php

I am reading file row by row and a row looks like this :

```php
$line = "  class="authors"> asdasdasdasd class="title" "
```

I save it in a variable `$line`. My goal is to extract all values of the key `class=""` for a line, that are set like `class="author"`. So I want to save in an array all values like this: `["authors", "title" ...]`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: add what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little bit difficult to understand your question but let me show you an example:

**Code:**

```
<?php

 $line = "  class=\"authors\"> asdasdasdasd class=\"title\" ";

 preg_match_all("/class=\"([^\"]+)\"/", $line, $out);
 print_r($out);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => class="authors"
            [1] => class="title"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => authors
            [1] => title
        )
)
```

To complete the answer to your question regarding the result of 
`[ "authors", "title" .... ]`

**Code:**

```
 $desired_array = array_merge($out[1]);
 print_r($desired_array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => authors
    [1] => title
)

// same as:
// ['authors', 'title']
```

Hopefully this helps you to understand how it works.